# if condition inside function is not working as desired when function called with command line arguments inside find statement

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/bin/bash

# Code to generate script usage
if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]] && [[ "$#" -ne 2 ]]; then
    flag=1;
elif ! [[ "$1" == "abcd" || "$1" == "dcba" ]]; then 
    echo "Invalid"
    flag=1;
fi

while [ $# -gt 1 ]
do
    case $2 in
        'streams')
            ;;
        *)
            echo "unrecognised optional arg $2"; flag=1;
            ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ "$flag" == "1" ]; then
    echo "Usage:"
    exit
fi

function main {

arg1=$1
streams=$2
    if [ "${streams}" == "streams" ]; then
        echo entering here
    else
       echo entering there
    fi
}

parent_dir=`pwd`
find $parent_dir -name "*" -type d | while read d; do
    cd $denter code here
    main $1 $2
done
```

Why the code does not enter "entering here" when script run with arguments "abcd" and "streams" ?
I feel that function having two arguments is causing the problem, code was working fine with one argument

Comment: Try running with `-x` and see to what `[ "${streams}" == "streams" ]` expands.

Comment: What is that you are doing here by these statements   `cd $denter code here
    main $1 $2`

Comment: Your code produces an error you don't mention. `$ ./test_script.bash abcd streams
./test_script.bash: line 41 : cd: code: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Inian I'm fairly sure that's an artefact of SO's editor.

Comment: @Inian that line somehow got edited. It is cd $d

Answer (score 2):

Several things you might want to fix in your code, before attempts are made to find the specific problem. It is possible that it will disappear after modifying your script accordingly. If the problem is still alive, I'll edit my answer with a solution. If you decide to apply the following changes, please update your code in the question.

1. Consistent usage of either `[[` or `[`. `[[` is a Bash keyword similar to (but more powerful than) the `[` command. 
   See

   - [Bash FAQ 31](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031)
   - [Tests And Conditionals](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/TestsAndConditionals)

   Unless you're writing for POSIX sh, I recommend `[[`.
2. Use `((` for arithmetic expressions. `((...))` is an arithmetic command, which returns an exit status of 0 if the expression is nonzero, or 1 if the expression is zero. Also used as a synonym for `let`, if assignments are needed. See [Arithmetic Expression](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ArithmeticExpression).
3. Use the variable `PWD` instead of `pwd`. `PWD` is a builtin variable in all *POSIX* shells that contains the current working directory. `pwd(1)` is a *POSIX* utility that prints the name of the current working directory to stdout. Unless you're writing for some **non**-*POSIX* system, there is no reason to waste time executing `pwd(1)` rather than just using `PWD`.
4. The `function` keyword is not portable. I suggest you to avoid using it and simply write `function_name() { your code here; } # Usage`
5. `$parent_dir` is not double-quoted. "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and **every** expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. See

   - [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes)
   - [Arguments](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments)
6. [ShellCheck](http://www.shellcheck.net) your code before uploading.

Comment: This is a good answer. Note how quotes works in command substitutions: `"$(command "$var")"` is valid quoting and can be broken apart like this: `command "$var"` and `"$(...)"`

Comment: Regarding point 4: `[[` and `((` aren't portable either, but they provide tangible benefits in exchange for sacrificing portability. The only reason I can come up with to use `function` is to define a function with the same name as a pre-existing alias (which, aside from almost never being necessary, is still possible with POSIX-compliant code.) I'm pretty sure the keyword only exists for the benefit of code being ported from `ksh` (which does make a distinction, irrelevant in `bash`, between functions defined with and without the keyword.)

Comment: @chepner Thank you for this comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace the while condition logic with an if condition, so that shift is no longer required. Shift was the devil I was facing I found.

#!/bin/bash

# Code to generate script usage
if [[ "$#" -ne 1 ]] && [[ "$#" -ne 2 ]]; then
    flag=1;
elif ! [[ "$1" == "abcd" || "$1" == "dcba" ]]; then 
    echo "Invalid"
    flag=1;
fi
#while [[ $# -gt 1 ]]
#do
#    case $2 in
#       'streams')
#           ;;
#        *)
#            echo "unrecognised optional arg $2"; flag=1;
#            ;;
#    esac
#    shift
#done

if [[ $2 == "streams" ]]; then
   :
elif [[ (-z $2) ]]; then
    : 
else
    echo "unrecognised optional arg $2"; flag=1;
fi


if [[ "$flag" == "1" ]]; then
    echo "Usage:"
    exit
fi

function main {

streams=$2

    if [[ "${streams}" == "streams" ]]; then
        echo entering here
    else
       echo entering there
    fi
}

parent_dir=`pwd`
find $parent_dir -name "*" -type d | while read d; do
    cd $d
    main $1 $2
done
```

Comment: But I dont know whether this is the right way to solve it